# Select only elements you want in string/array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this `$arr = array(2, -3, 6, 1);`

And I only want to select the positive numbers to be able to sum the others between them.

So I wrote this code, but I'm a bit lost on how to select the elements I only want to do something with them, like summing them.

```
$sum = implode(",", $arr);

  for($i = 0; $i <= strlen($sum); $i++) {
    if($i <= 0) {
    } else {
      return explode(",", array_sum($i));
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "select"?

Comment: use `array_filter`, no need to use an explicit loop: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton I edited the title. Sorry about that, I just want to be able to select only element I want in the array. And sum the others together.

Answer (score 4):

Use array_fliter to filter the value, and array_sum to sum the array.

```
   array_sum(array_filter($array, function($v){return $v>0;});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I can't figure out how does that works.
I have $arr = array(2, -3, 6, 1);

Answer (score 0):

Use array_filter with callback function like below :

```
<?php
    $arr = array(2, -3, 6, 1);
    function positive($a){
        if($a > 0){
            return $a;
        }

    }
    $newArr = array_sum(array_filter($arr, "positive"));
    print_r($newArr);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `array_reduce`:

```
$arr = array(2, -3, 6, 1);

$result = array_reduce($arr, function($c, $i) { return $i > 0 ? $c + $i : $c; });

echo $result;
```